# Ubuntu 22.04 Terminal gives "waiting for cache lock. Could not get lock/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 3893 (apt)

Tags: command-line, drivers, apt

Unable to install some apts (printer driver) as terminal could not get lock

Answer (score 0):

Use the command line to kill any running process. For that use the following commands

```
sudo killall apt apt-get
```

If that doesn't work follow the below commands.

```
ps aux | grep -i apt
```

This will return id of the processes running apt

```
sudo kill process_id
```

Replace the process_id with the number you got in the output of previous command.

Check if the process was killed by running the ‘ps aux | grep -i apt’ command. If it is still running, force kill it with SIGKILL signal:

```
sudo kill -9 process_id
```